# MySql avg() function not returning correct value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am learning about the average function and tried it as follows:

Account Table using open_emp_id field:

```
+-------------+
| open_emp_id |
+-------------+
|           1 |
|           1 |
|           1 |
|           1 |
|           1 |
|           1 |
|           1 |
|           1 |
|          10 |
|          10 |
|          10 |
|          10 |
|          10 |
|          10 |
|          10 |
|          13 |
|          13 |
|          13 |
|          16 |
|          16 |
|          16 |
|          16 |
|          16 |
|          16 |
+-------------+
```

My SQL query:

```
SELECT avg(open_emp_id)
FROM account;
```

My Result:

```
+------------------+
| avg(open_emp_id) |
+------------------+
|           8.8750 |
+------------------+
```

How is the result not 10?

(1+ 10 + 13 + 16) / 4 = 10

Comment: Because you don't have 4 rows, you have a lot more.  Your calculation is `AVG(DISTINCT open_emp_id)` -- but I advise you never to use `AVG(DISTINCT)`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff why shouln't I user `avg(distinct)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `avg(expression)` function returns the average of all input values.

You have 8 `1`'s = 8

You have 7 `10`s = 70

You have 3 `13`'s = 39

You have 6 `16`'s = 96

All the above added together is `213`.

You have a total of 24 input elements hence, 213 / 24 = 8.875